# How to enable the GridView paging after showing 12 elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and now I am having an issue in the system that I am working on it. I have a GridView and I already enabled the paging functionality on it. What I want now is showing 12 or 14 elements in the GridView and then use paging to show the other next 12 elements, so how to do that?

My ASP.NET code:

```
<!-- Content Goes Here! -->
                                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" CssClass="datatable"
                                            CellPadding="0" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None" 
                                        OnDataBinding="GridView3_DataBinding" AllowPaging="True">

                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Quiz" 
                                                    SortExpression="Title" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" 
                                                    HeaderText="Division" 
                                                    SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Total Number of Participants" 
                                                    HeaderText="Total Number of Participants" ReadOnly="True" 
                                                    SortExpression="Total Number of Participants"/>
                                            </Columns>

                                            <RowStyle CssClass="row" />

                                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle CssClass="sortasc"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>
                                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
                                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
                                        </asp:GridView>

                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" 
                                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.Quiz.Title, dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut,  COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username) AS [Total Number of Participants]
        FROM         dbo.employee INNER JOIN
                              dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username INNER JOIN
                              dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID INNER JOIN
                              dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode
        GROUP BY dbo.Quiz.Title, dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut
        ORDER BY dbo.Quiz.Title"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**So how to do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AllowPaging="True" PageSize="12"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Content Goes Here! -->
                                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" CssClass="datatable"
                                        CellPadding="0" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None" 
                                    OnDataBinding="GridView3_DataBinding" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="12">

                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Quiz" 
                                                SortExpression="Title" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" 
                                                HeaderText="Division" 
                                                SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Total Number of Participants" 
                                                HeaderText="Total Number of Participants" ReadOnly="True" 
                                                SortExpression="Total Number of Participants"/>
                                        </Columns>

                                        <RowStyle CssClass="row" />

                                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle CssClass="sortasc"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>
                                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
                                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
                                    </asp:GridView>

                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" 
                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.Quiz.Title, dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut,  COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username) AS [Total Number of Participants]
    FROM         dbo.employee INNER JOIN
                          dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username INNER JOIN
                          dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID INNER JOIN
                          dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode
    GROUP BY dbo.Quiz.Title, dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut
    ORDER BY dbo.Quiz.Title"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

add below attribute in your asp:gridview

```
 OnPageIndexChanging="grdview_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="12" AllowPaging="True"
```

then in CodeBehind Add below function

```
  protected void grdeview_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // your gridview ID 
        GridView3.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView3.Datasource = your datasource ;
        GridView3.DataBind();
        // or your can create separate function for bindGridview. and than call it directly here.  
    }
```